# How To Correct Implement IOperationInvoker

Tags: c#, wcf, aop

Now I'm refactoring old WCF and I need redirect some old WCF service requests to new WCF service.

What I do is intercept per old WCF service call use class implement IOperationInvoker. But I not sure how to set the **outsputs** in the invoke signature as below.

```
object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs);
```

Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Routing Service to distribute old request to the new one(filter by action,endpoint and so on), learn more from MSDN about Routing Service.

For my points, it's high degree of coupling if you handle this situation, you should also edit you code and compile again if you need more restructure in the future.

for Routing Service, just update the config file, no change in the old project.